# Load template for specific subdomain

Tags: subdomains

I'd like to be able to set a wordpress theme for certain subdomains, but still load the same content for all installations.

For example, I have www.domain.com that loads the default template with default content. I'd also like to have mobile.domain.com, that too loads the same content but a separate template.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Usually in this type of scenario the template is the same, but a different style sheet is loaded when a mobile browser is detected. If you want a plugin to take care of that, there are some good ones out there like [WP Touch](http://www.bravenewcode.com/store/plugins/wptouch-pro/) (commercial) or [plenty](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=mobile) of free ones too.

Comment: We have a custom template made up, and I want the functionality to choose any kind of template based on the subdomain, not just limiting to mobile site design. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail about the *kind* of template you'd be serving up, the best I can advise is that you can use the ['template_redirect'](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L7) hook to override the entire Template Hierarchy.

A more delicate way to do this would be by using on of the more specific filters. Each of the conditional get_*_template() functions in template-loader.php has a filter of its own which you can use to return your own template name. Look in [includes/themes.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/theme.php#L745) to see those filters.

Most of them end up using get_query_template(), which dynamically creates the filter name in a consistant way, but some of the others like author and category are separate - look around to find which if any suits you best under different circumstances.